# Who are aware of the question ban formula?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban, ban

I know that the question ban formula of stack exchange is very secret and it's not revealed in public. But since stack exchange is run by the community, someone must know it. So who is the formula revealed to? Do you need to reach a certain reputation level so you are recognized as a trusted member and then the formula is revealed?

Comment: Nobody except Stack Exchange developers.

Comment: Nobody except the Stack Exchange developers would really need to be aware of it. No amount of reputation would grant you access to it.

Comment: Oh I thought stack exchange was run by the community so people from the community would be the developers.

Comment: I'm aware of the most contributing factors and used it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/885476/am-i-quality-banned-for-questions).

Comment: @rene how did you find out?

Comment: I read a lot of comments and hang out with the wrong people.

Comment: @rene I was expecting something more specific.

Comment: I bet you were ...

Comment: @rene It's not what you are thinking, I am just very curious. And I'm not under a question ban.

Comment: Stack Exchange is a private company, only developers employed by the company know this sort of thing.

Comment: You fell into this marketing trap. SO is not run by the community. They just want us to think we would have anything to say and if they don't like what we say, they will just do what they want. This was proven by the Great Meta Tire Fire 2019

Answer (score 10):

Only the Stack Exchange developers (and perhaps a handful Community Managers) know this. It's coded into the system, and perhaps documented in an internal document, but no amount of reputation will reveal this information. If that would be the case, I'm sure somebody would have leaked it by now.

Really smart people like @rene were able to reverse engineer part of it, resulting in [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/885476/am-i-quality-banned-for-questions), but it's by no means official.